# Search function on listview

Tags: c#

I am altering the question now!

I have the search working using the following:

```
//check the array for a match
        foreach (Delivery d in mainForm.myDeliveries)
        {
            if (d.DeliveryName == searchValue)
            {
                ListViewItem item = lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName);
                item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryAddress);
                item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryDay);
                item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryTime);
                item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryMeal);
                item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryInstructions);
                item.SubItems.Add(d.DeliveryStatus);

            }
        }
```

My question is, what is the best way to now search all the other values, to make a complete search?
I know i could do if else statements and go through address, day, time, etc.

Is there a better way to acheive this?
And at the moment, the user has to enter the entire name to get the result, can i make it if they only enter a part of the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all items from your list view and only add the ones that match the search criteria:

```
lstDeliveryDetails.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < myDeliveries.Count; i++)
{
    Delivery d = (Delivery)mainForm.myDeliveries[i];

    if (d.DeliveryName == searchValue)
         lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName);
}
```

Comment: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Luke change it to lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName); Similarly you've to add your subItems also.

Comment: Haha, I realised the error of my ways and then saw what you wrote too! For some reason, it's not returning anything in the listview :(

Comment: check if you get any matches using a breakpoint or msgbox as you've already used.

Answer (score 0):

Change your display method such that it accepts a Delivery list argument (or array) like this

```
private void displayDeliveries(List<Delivery> deliveries)
```

and change its definition accordingly

In your btnSearch get the list of selected deliveries in List and pass into the displayDeliveries method

While initialising your listView send mainForm.myDeliveries as an argument

**Update**

Get the keyword from the user and check like this

```
if (d.DeliveryName.Contains(searchValue))
```

You can also try incremental search by handling the TextChanged event of textbox if the list is small.